# Elementary Number Theory.. If a divides

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elementary Number Theory.. If a divides..](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198716/elementary-number-theory-if-a-divides)

If a divides (2c+3d) and if (-a) divides (c+d) then show that 3a divides 3c.

The only progres I can say i've made is that it is basically asking to show that a divides c, because the 3 is only a constant.

Comment: This site is for MathematicA not MathematicS!

Comment: If (-a) divides (c+d) then also a divides (c+d). If a|c+d then a|3*(c+d). Take it from there (but on a site appropriate to this question).

Comment: A lost pink panda